# BC66 Registration denied. AT+COPS returns CME Error 30 which is No network service

Tags: gsm, firmware, quectel

I'm trying to connect a BC66 module with a Vodafone Italy NB-IOT sim to internet.

I've tried the following log:

`ATE1
OK

ATI
Quectel_Ltd
Quectel_BC66
Revision: BC66NBR01A10
OK

AT+QCCID
+QCCID: [CENSORED]
OK

AT+CGSN=0
[CENSORED]
OK

AT+CGSN=1
+CGSN: [CENSORED]
OK

AT+CIMI
[CENSORED]
OK

AT+CPSMS=0
OK

AT+QSCLK=0
OK

AT+CEREG=5
OK

AT+CSCON=1
OK

AT+QNBIOTEVENT=1,1
OK

AT+QBAND=1,20
OK

AT+QCGDEFCONT="IP"," m2m.vodafone.it" [APN Given to me]
OK

AT+CGPADDR=1
OK`

but these are the results:

`
CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 3,,,,,0,0

AT+CEREG?
CEREG: 5,3,,,,,0,0
OK

CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

AT+CEREG?
+CEREG: 5,0,,,,,0,0
OK

+CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 3,,,,,0,0
`

I also tried `AT+COPS=1,2,"22210"` but with no avail because I get these results:

`
+CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

+CME ERROR: no network service

+CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 2,,,,,0,0

+CEREG: 0,,,,,0,0
`

Any possible idea on what I can possibly try?
Best regards.

To see my attempts check the text I've wrote.

Comment: Now the CEREG returns stat = 3 (registration denied) and I have no idea on why. Tomorrow I will call the client support of the SIM and ask if it is blocked.